# How do i make HTTP request with support javascript in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I'm trying to create a simple app in Node.js that make a **`HTTP`** request to a site and scrape it, i used **`request`** npm package to making request but it didn't support javascript, i mean the site need to run **`<script>`** tag but **`request`** doesn't let it to run **`script`**.

What can i do to make **`HTTP`** request with support **`JS`**?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify - do you want to run the JS code in the web page you loaded in the HTTP request?

Comment: The app problem was elsewhere and thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

start by declaring it

```
var request = require('request');
```

now that you have the thing required (on a node or web page, my experience is in angular), use the function you declared.

```
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
})
```

the first line says "make a network request at http://www.google.com" then you're setting up the inside of your function to look at the responce. Depending on what you want your response to contain, look at and parse different parts of it "inside" this function (where the console.log is), or better yet call a parse/ do things function from inside once you have the data.

Comment: inside a node app, you really shouldn't need a <script>. A node app is all script all the time.

Comment: The app problem was elsewhere and thanks for your response.